# Sort NSMutableArray with custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have an iOS app with a `NSMutableArray` which contains many rows worth of data (split up into 3 segments) - as shown below:

```
[PFUser object, stringData, floatValue]
       .             .          4.3
       .             .          5.9
       .             .          1.1
       .             .          9.32
       .             .          0.024
```

The above diagram shows how the array is split up and the data types that are stored in the array. But those data types are not keys or anything. So I can't do something like `valueForKey`.

An example of what the array looks like:

```
@[@[userObject, @"hello", @234.1441],
  @[userObject, @"sdfsg", @94.33],
  @[userObject, @"wrfdo", @24.897]
];
```

So from the example above you can see that I have arrays in arrays.

I would like to sort the array by reading the 3 segment which contains the float values.

How can I do this? I have looked online and read a lot about using `NSSortDescriptor` but the problem I have is that all the examples always seem to use simple strings or an array with numbers only.

Is there a way to use `NSSortDescriptor` in an array with custom objects like mine?

Comment: I am certain that cannot be done in a clean way. Because you will violate the sorting invariants all the time. create a custom class to store the connected data.

Comment: To be clear, you have an array of arrays where each array has 3 values, correct? The example you posted is missing commas after each inner array.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [sortUsingComparator:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingComparator:)

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSArray *arr1 = obj1;
    NSArray *arr2 = obj2;
    return [arr1[2] compare:arr2[2]];
}];
```

Or even (thanks to [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy)'s suggestion):

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^(NSArray *arr1, NSArray *arr2) {
    return [arr1[2] compare:arr2[2]];
}];
```

If you have a immutable array, you can use [sortedArrayUsingComparator:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator:)

Comment: This can be made even easier by changing the type of `obj1` and `obj2` to `NSArray *` from `id`. Then the body can be one line.

Comment: For questions "How do I sort..." the correct answer is always either "use sortUsingComparator and write the code" or "no, you can't sort dictionaries" :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 true :))

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

For example in your case to sort the array by float value :

```
NSMutableArray *array = // Init your array;

array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    float value1 = [[obj1 objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    float value2 = [[obj2 objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];

    if (value1 < value2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if (value1 > value2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}]];
```

With this method you can sort as you like.

Comment: 1) Why create the mutable array? 2) Why bother with the float values? Just get each `NSNumber` from index 2 and compare those two objects directly. No need for the `if/else`.

Comment: See the answer by Cristik for what I meant. It's must simpler.

Comment: `sortUsingComparitor:` is definitely the thing, but why not just `return [obj1[2] compare:obj2[2]]`?

Comment: I create a mutable array because sortedArrayUsingComparator return an array. It is an example with float the code must be adjust. I added the if / else to compare any object with any object, for example sort by string and float.

Comment: "the code must be adjust" - nonsense. You have NSNumber. NSNumber knows perfectly fine how to compare with another NSNumber.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. Yes but if you want for example to compare PFUser with a float ?? You must implement this (if / else).

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray has a call sortUsingComparator, which takes a comparison result block as parameter. So Something like this:

```
[users sortUsingComparator:
     ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
     {
         PFUser* userA = (PFUser*)obj1;
         PFUser* userB = (PFUser*)obj2;

        return [userA.floatValue compare:userB.floatValue];

     }];
```

Comment: This won't work. It's not an array of `PFUser` objects.

Comment: Who ever upvoted this doesn't understand the question. This answer won't work.